# How to check if certain position in array is modified using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I don't understand how I can check if a certain position in an array is been modified or not. Below is an example:

```
int array[5];

array[2] = 23;
array[4] = 23;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == ????){
        cout << "in array";
    } else {
        cout << "not in array";
    }
}
```

So I wanted to know how would I get it so the `if` statement is checking if the item has been modified. So once I becomes 2 it will says it's in array and if not the it should print 'not in array'.

This has to be done using pointers.

Comment: Google `std::optional` if you want things that may or may not exist. "_This has to be done using pointers._" Not any more! Pointers should be used to point, not indicate optionality. Anyway, what does "modified or not" mean? If you initialised them all properly, to zero, then you could check whether or not they were still zero. But then you don't know whether they are _deliberately_ zero, so to speak. I'm VTC as unclear because it's not clear what you need to do or why.

Comment: So if data has been added to that position. The reason why i cant make them all 0 is that data[2] could be set to zero. Meaning that it would say the whole list is in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is undefined behavior because `array[0]` isn't initialized. So when you compare it in your `if`, what will happen?

You could initialize them all to a value that you consider as "not modified", and check for this value. For instance:

```
int array[5] = {}; // initializes all elements to the default value for int, which is 0
```

And then, in your `if`:

```
if (array[i] != 0 ) {
```

If you can't do that because you need the full range of `int` values, then you can use `std::optional` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
int main() {
    std::optional<int> array[5];

    array[2] = 23;

    array[4] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (array[i]) {
            std::cout << "in array" << std::endl;
        }
        else { std::cout << "not in array" << std::endl; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be bad idea to set all the values to NULL and then check if the items are null or not?

Comment: @Pouria it is an array of `int`s. Setting an `int` to `0` you cannot distinguish between `0` = no value and the value `0`, thats what `std::optional` nicely solves

Comment: @Pouria Would not help. `int` object is simply a collection of bits that represent some integer value. There is no way to tell whether the value has been changed/set without reserving some special value for this purpose (such as 0 originally in the answer).

Comment: @Pouria `NULL` is just a macro for `0` or something that will convert to `0`, such as `std::nullptr_t` or even `((void*)0)`. It sounds like you want to have functionality like `std::optional`, I added an example for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. In C++, it's impossible to determine if an object is *uninitialized*. Any attempt to read the value of an uninitialized object is Undefined Behavior. They're effectively write-only.

(You might also have a problem with the terminology, or a lack of understanding. `array[0]` is in the array from the very start, it's just not yet initialized. )

You might use `std::map<int, int> values` instead. It can truly be empty (`values.empty()==true`) When you write `values[2]=0`, a new value is added, and `values.size()` will be `1` to reflect the new number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how I can check if a certain position in an array is been modified or not.

On x86 you can set a hardware breakpoint on read/write/execute access to a value at a specific address of length of up to 8 bytes. On Linux one API for that is [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) with `PERF_TYPE_BREAKPOINT` event type. The value of the event counter is how many of interesting accesses to the value at the address have been made.

Comment: Yes, but this user probably isn't at a point where they should be doing things like that.

Comment: @underscore_d May be, but still it is useful to be aware that a method exists.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using two arrays. A `bool` array to store the initialization state, and another array to keep desired objects.
(However `std::array` or `std::vector` would be better choices than using  normal arrays, but that's a different concern)

E.g.

```
constexpr unsigned int ArrayLen = 5;

bool isInitialized[ArrayLen] = {false};
MyType myArray[ArrayLen];  // In your case `MyType = int`
...

// When setting/resetting update both arrays
void Set(int i, MyType obj)
{
    assert(i < ArrayLen);
    isInitialized[i] = true;
    myArray[i] = std::move(obj);
}
...

// check isInitialized array first before accessing an element
unsigned int targetIndex = 2;
if (isInitialized[targetIndex])
{
    auto& obj = myArray[targetIndex];
    // use `obj` ...
} else {
    // object in `targetIndex` is not initialized
}
```

In `C++17` you can use `std::optional` so that the initialization state doesn't need to be separately maintained but instead both the state and the object will be bound to a single `std::optional` object.